# convert JSON text string to Pandas, but each row cell ends up as an array of values inside

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, pandas, json-normalize

I manage to extract a time-series of prices from a web-portal. The data arrives in a json format, and I convert them into a pandas dataFrame.

Unfortunately, the data for the different bands come in a text string, and I can't seem to extract them out properly.

The below is the json data I extract

[image]

I convert them into a pandas dataframe using this code

```
data = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['prices'])
```

and get them like this

[image]

I need to extract (for example) the data in the column ClosePrice out, so that I can do data analysis and cleansing on them.

I tried using

```
data['closePrice'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns = lambda x: "string"+str(x+1))
```

but it doesn't really work.

Is there any way to either
a) when I convert the json to dataFrame, such that the prices within the closePrice, bidPrice etc are extracted in individual columns OR
b) if they were saved in the dataFrame, extract the text strings within them, such that I can extract the prices (e.g. the bid, ask and lastTraded) within the text string?

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to extract the data from the `dict`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = r.json()

# print(data)

{'prices': [{'closePrice': {'ask': 1.16042, 'bid': 1.16027, 'lastTraded': None},
                        'highPrice': {'ask': 1.16052, 'bid': 1.16041, 'lastTraded': None},
                        'lastTradedVolume': 74,
                        'lowPrice': {'ask': 1.16038, 'bid': 1.16026, 'lastTraded': None},
                        'openPrice': {'ask': 1.16044, 'bid': 1.16038, 'lastTraded': None},
                        'snapshotTime': '2018/09/28 21:49:00',
                        'snapshotTimeUTC': '2018-09-28T20:49:00'}]}

df = pd.json_normalize(data['prices'])
```

**Output:**

```py
|    |   lastTradedVolume | snapshotTime        | snapshotTimeUTC     |   closePrice.ask |   closePrice.bid | closePrice.lastTraded   |   highPrice.ask |   highPrice.bid | highPrice.lastTraded   |   lowPrice.ask |   lowPrice.bid | lowPrice.lastTraded   |   openPrice.ask |   openPrice.bid | openPrice.lastTraded   |
|---:|-------------------:|:--------------------|:--------------------|-----------------:|-----------------:|:------------------------|----------------:|----------------:|:-----------------------|---------------:|---------------:|:----------------------|----------------:|----------------:|:-----------------------|
|  0 |                 74 | 2018/09/28 21:49:00 | 2018-09-28T20:49:00 |          1.16042 |          1.16027 |                         |         1.16052 |         1.16041 |                        |        1.16038 |        1.16026 |                       |         1.16044 |         1.16038 |                        |
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively brute force way, using links from other stackOverflow.

```
# load and extract the json data
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url + '/session', json=data)
loc = <url>
dat1 = s.get(loc)
dat1 = pd.DataFrame(dat1.json()['prices'])

# convert the object list into individual columns
dat2 = pd.DataFrame()
dat2[['bidC','askC', 'lastP']] = pd.DataFrame(dat1.closePrice.values.tolist(), index= dat1.index)
dat2[['bidH','askH', 'lastH']] = pd.DataFrame(dat1.highPrice.values.tolist(), index= dat1.index)
dat2[['bidL','askL', 'lastL']] = pd.DataFrame(dat1.lowPrice.values.tolist(), index= dat1.index)
dat2[['bidO','askO', 'lastO']] = pd.DataFrame(dat1.openPrice.values.tolist(), index= dat1.index)
dat2['tStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dat1.snapshotTime)
dat2['volume'] = dat1.lastTradedVolume
```

get the equivalent below

[image]